# Why don't certain antonym pairs get rearranged often?

Tags: english, frequency

Why don't certain antonym pairs get rearranged often? We have little and big, small and large, but almost never hear little and large.

Another example: weak and strong, soft and tough, but never weak and tough.

Comment: I'm not enough of a semanticist to feel confident posting this as an answer, but I don't think these synonyms are as exact as you make them sound. "Faulty" and "bad" don't mean the same thing, nor do "arrive" and "enter": you don't arrive a building, and I don't call my cat faulty when she misbehaves.

Comment: Are you asking why some words are used more than others that have almost the same meaning? There are always variations, is the answer; they're what keep language evolution working. Look at wildflowers in the wild and notice how different each one is. That's like individual word use by individual speakers; it varies all over the lot, over the centuries.

Comment: [Little and Large](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_and_Large) was a famous British comedic double-act. So maybe the phrase is commoner in some places than others. (I'm not sure there's a single answer to this question: factors such as sounding pleasing, different shades of meaning, habit/set phrases, will all play a role.)

Comment: @StuartF: Maybe the surprising element in "little and large" is part of the commedy of that British duo.

Comment: "Big and small" is also very common.

Answer (score 4):

Presumably because those pairs of synonyms -- *little/small, strong/tough* etc. -- actually differ somewhat in semantics and usage.

This is easy to see with the second example: not everything strong is tough and not everything weak is soft, nor vice versa.

> a strong/?tough argument
> a tough/?strong steak
> a weak/?soft correlation
> the soft/?weak bigotry of low expectations

With the first example the denotations seem to overlap more, but *little* and *big* have an emotive association that *small* and *large* lack.

> You big/?large palooka!
> What a cute little/?small kitten!

I would guess that *little* and *big* tend to be acquired earlier by children, too, though I don't have any data on this.

So, in terms of meaning and usage, *little* is a more exact antonym of *big* than *small* is, and similarly for the other examples, which is presumably why they remain aligned in speakers' minds.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good demonstration of **conventionalisation** in natural language. The conventionalisation goes so far, the even the order of the antonyms tend to be fixed, as in *black and white* or *good and evil*. The conventionalisation reduces the surprisal of the antonym phrase and eases its processing in the human brain. Any derivation from that would be **[marked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markedness)** in linguistic terminology.

Comment: When I first saw Willy Russell's stage play *Shirley Valentine*, I was surprised that she referred to a meal of "chips and egg". To me it had always been "egg and chips", and "chips and egg" sounded wrong.